# Point class objects with same name in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a class project. We have to set the values of 2 `coordinate pairs` then find the length between them. I am having an error where I use an `object` called Point throughout the `program`. It gives me an error saying that it is a duplicate `method`. I have attached my `class` and marked my `error`

```
public class Point 
{
private double distance;
private double x1;
private double x2;
private double y1;
private double y2;

public Point(double x1) //ERROR
{
    this.x1 = x1;
}
public void setX1(double x1)
{
    this.x1 = x1;
}
public double getx1(double x1)
{
    return x1;
}
public Point(double x2) //ERROR
{
    this.x2 = x2;
}
public void setX2(double x2)
{
    this.x2 = x2;
}
public double getX2(double x2)
{
    return x2;
}
public Point(double y1) //ERROR
{
    this.y1 = y1;
}
public void setY1(double y1)
{
    this.y1 = y1;
}
public double getY1(double y1)
{
    return y1;
}
public Point(double y2) // ERROR
{
    this.y2 = y2;
}
public void setY2(double y2)
{
    this.y2 = y2;
}
public double getY2(double y2)
{
    return y2;
}
public double distance()
{
    return Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2.0) + (Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2))));
}

}
```

I have done something similar to this where I used the same name and it  worked so I'm not sure what is wrong here. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I have this code that is similarly set up but throws no errors. Why is that?

```
public class Car 
{
private String make;
private String model;
private int year;

public Car()
{

}
public Car(String make)
{
    this.make = make;
}
public void setMake(String carMake)
{
    this.make = carMake;
}
public String getMake()
{
    return make;
}
public void Car(String model)
{
    this.model = model;
}
public void setModel(String carModel)
{
    this.model = carModel;
}
public String getModel()
{
    return model;
}
public Car(int year)
{
    this.year = year;
}
public void setYear(int carYear)
{
    this.year = carYear;
}
public int getYear(int year)
{
    return year;
}
public boolean isAntique()
{
    if ((2015 - year) >= 45){
        return true;
    }
    if ((2015 - year) < 45){
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Car Make: " + make + " Car Model: " + model + " Car Year: " + year + " Antique? " + isAntique();
}
```

}

Comment: your constructor exists multiple times with the same signature `Point(double)`. How should the compiler decide which one it has to call if you create an object as `new Point(1.0);` ?

Comment: Show and indicate the offending code and also show the **complete** error message. We're **much** smarter if we don't have to guess.

Comment: It exists four times, actually.

Comment: I'm sorry to sound like I don't know much but I'm in a beginners Java course. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You would benefit by reading an introductory chapter (or two) on Java classes and constructors: [Java Object-Oriented Concepts Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

Comment: @Todd Imagine you have 4 papers with `Number` as title(method signature), and you should bring your chef the one with Number as title, but just a single paper. How would you decide which one you should hand him? The same happens with the compiler.

Comment: Your getter methods (probably) shouldn't take a parameter, and then return it. You almost certainly want `public double getx1()` instead (similarly for other getters).

Comment: From a modelling perspective, this class isn't a "point", it is a line. A point should be a class with just (x, y) coordinates; you can then have a simpler "line" class containing the two end points, and define the distance method on that.

Comment: On a side note, a mathematical point only has one set of coordinates. Here, there are two points. In geometry, this is a segment. The distance between its two extremities are its length. Were I to write this code myself, I would make a point defined by an X and Y, and a segment defined by two points, with `length` calculating the distance between the two points (the distance computation could be in a utility class if you expect to use it again). Just some idea.

Comment: @Todd Notice that you don´t have a constructor with the same Signature in your new edited case. you have a constructor `Car(String)` and a method `Car(String)`. This happend due to you inserting the keyword `void`, which is not part of the constructor syntax. If you remove it, you will get the same error message.

Comment: It worked previously bcoz in Car class you have only 2 constructor Car(String make) and Car(int year) while Car(String model) has return type void so it actually method and not named as per standards

Answer (score 2):

```
public Point(double x1) //ERROR
{
    this.x1 = x1;
}

public Point(double x2) //ERROR
{
    this.x2 = x2;
}
```

Let's consider these two constructors to be working properly and the compiler does not throw any error.
Now when the constructor is called,

`Point object=new Point(10.00)`

*which point do you think will get initialised?* *x1 or x2?*

To avoid these things **you cannot have two constructos with same signature.**

Answer (score 1):

`public Point(double x1)` and `public Point(double y2)` are the same thing. Which one should be called if you wrote `new Point(1.0);`?

The constructors and methods need to differ by name, parameter types or amounts of parameters. You most likely won't have a constructor that takes a single double value, since it's hard to define a point with just one coordinate.

I'd suspect that the only (or at least the primary) constructor would be one that takes 4 `double` values.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple functions with the same name unless they have different argument types. This is called [overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). (I imagine this is why you can recall doing so in the past).

You could, for example, do the following:

```
public Point(String s) {
    ...
}
public Point(int i) {
    ...
}
public Point(double f) {
    ...
}
public Point(int i, double f) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: in java class cannot have duplicate constructors, by duplicate, we mean 2 or more constructors with same argument types and order, in your case you have 2 constructors with double argument, which counts as the same method for the compiler.

```
public Point(double x1) //first declared constructor with double argument
{
    this.x1 = x1;
}

public Point(double x2) //remove this constructor
{
    this.x2 = x2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Signature

Java knows a method/constructor by its name and argument types (argument names are erased at compilation, they are mainly a development utility). The combination of method name and parameter types (e.g. `Point(double)`) is called the method's **signature**. **In any given class, you can find a signature only once**!

#### Why is that?

Here, you have `Point(double)` four times in the class.

When you call `new Point(13.37)`, the JVM has no means to know whether you are calling `Point(double x1)`, `Point(double x2)`, `Point(double y1)` or `Point(double y2)`. This is therefore forbidden and will be intercepted at compilation, producing an error.

#### What you can do

You should review your constructor to pass the 4 double values, or none at all and use the setters instead.

```
public Point() {
    // this is it, use setters to initialize the values
    // useful when using serialization
}

public Point(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;
}
```

#### Why is `Car` working?

Let's examine the signatures:

```
public Car()
public Car(String make)
public void Car(String model)
```

`Car()` and `Car(String)` are different obviously.

You also have a method `Car(String)` (object.Car("sth")`) and a constructor`Car(String)`(`new Car("sth")`). These are not the same, but the method is incorrect (calling a method as the class is not advised as it may be confusing, and actually confused you).

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your "public Point(..." methods

add single method
with

```
public Point(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "what is wrong?" Answers are more helpful if askers understand their problem so that they don't make the same mistake again. Plus, having an all-arg constructor is a design choice. You can also choose the no-arg + accessors only.

Comment: I think, in this case showing the right code is the way to "understand"

Comment: I tend to disagree, since the asker is a Java beginner and does not know/understand the concepts of erasure and overloading. Yes, making this will work, but why? Why did it fail with the previous constructors?

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise identical method signatures must have different parameter types, not parameter names. During run time, the JVM doesn't even notice the parameter name, it's just a handy way for the programmer to keep track of things. As such your constructor exists four times, all identical (from Java's perspective).

Also, it's good form to name your parameter something different than the field you're setting. For instance I usually add a p for parameter in front just so you don't loose track of which particular y2 or whatever it is you're talking about.